# Z sorting multiple nodes in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting

I'm trying to build a game in iOS and am currently using Objective-C. The problem I'm running into is Z-sorting different enemy and player nodes. This is my current code for Z-sorting just one enemy type, and I am only copying this code to z-sort every different type of enemy (Mob). This is leading to ALOT of code that all does essentially the same thing for different objects. The only way I know how to fix this problem is by using template functions, but Objective-C doesn't support that to my knowledge. There has to be a better way...

```
// If two monsters are standing on the same cell, we need to z sort them based on position
// south-western most body will be closest to the "camera" from players perspective
-(void) zSortMobs {
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
for (i = 0; i < self.maxMobs; i++) {
    Mob * mob = [self.mobs objectAtIndex: i];
    if (mob.state != 0) {

        for (j = 0; j < self.maxMobs; j++) {
            Mob * mob2 = [self.mobs objectAtIndex: j];
            if (mob2.state != 0) {
                if (mob != mob2) {
                    if (mob.z == mob2.z) {
                        if (mob.y < mob2.y) {
                            mob.z++;
                        }
                        else if (mob.y == mob2.y) {
                            if (mob.x < mob2.x) {
                                mob.z++;
                            }
                            else {
                                mob2.z++;
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            mob2.z++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                [mob setZPosition: mob.z];
                [mob2 setZPosition: mob2.z];
            }
        }

        for (j = 0; j < self.maxTanks; j++) {
            Tank * tank = [self.tanks objectAtIndex: j];
            if (tank.state != 0) {
                    if (mob.z == tank.z) {
                        if (mob.y < tank.y) {
                            mob.z++;
                        }
                        else if (mob.y == tank.y) {
                            if (mob.x < tank.x) {
                                mob.z++;
                            }
                            else {
                                tank.z++;
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            tank.z++;
                        }
                    }
                [mob setZPosition: mob.z];
                [tank setZPosition: tank.z];
            }
        }

        if (mob.z == self.gameScene.player.z) {
            if (mob.y < self.gameScene.player.y) {
                mob.z++;
            }
            else if (mob.y == self.gameScene.player.y) {
                if (mob.x < self.gameScene.player.x) {
                    mob.z++;
                }
                else {
                    self.gameScene.player.z++;
                }
            }
            else {
                self.gameScene.player.z++;
            }
        }
        [mob setZPosition: mob.z];
        [self.gameScene.player setZPosition: self.gameScene.player.z];
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You do not need templates in Objective-C, because it binds late. Simply use `id` typed references to write generic code. You can make it safer with protocol typing, if you want to.

Comment: Maybe problem with your coding structure.